# Regex pattern matching string iff it only contain certain allowed characters

Tags: python, regex

How do I write a regrex string that matches a string if and only if the string contains only certain allowed characters, let's say capital {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'} i.e. it should match `'A'`, `'ABC'`, `'CEA'`, and `'ABCEACBBCAED?`, but not `'AGV'`, `'AcD'`,or `'a'`?

```py
re.search(some_regex_string, some_string)
```

Comment: You can use `[A-E]+`

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi `[A-E]+` would still match partial strings that contain character clusters in the  [A-E] range. You will have to specify word boundaries at least, `\b[A-E]+\b`

Comment: @Filip: you need to use start/end anchors with that regex. That regex I gave was an idea of how to allow `A` to `E` characters. You need to write the regex as `^[A-E]+$` which will only match a string that contains only and only `A` to `E` characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this regex for matching the kind of sample data in your post.

```
^[A-E]+$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kH5uCY/1)**

In case you have a larger string where you want to only match tokens which has only `A` to `Z` characters, then in that case you can use word boundaries around the regex as this,

```
\b[A-E]+\b
```

Which will match only strings that contain `A` to `E` characters into the string.

**[Demo for matching intended strings in a larger string](https://regex101.com/r/kH5uCY/2)**